# What does ウン歳 mean?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, slang

I recently heard a woman describe herself as a 四十｛よんじゅう｝ウン歳｛さい｝. My guess is that it is the Japanese equivalent of "40-something", but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ウン](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/292369/meaning/m0u/) in this context means 'something', so it would be forty-something.

ウン is used as a filler for unspecific mumbling on other occasions also - like [here in "unnunkannun"](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BA%91%E4%BA%91%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%AC%E3%82%93-212969).

Also [see](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%82%93%E3%81%AC%E3%82%93).